# How to get instagram page url of an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram

I use instagram gem. I know how to get the image, likes and comments counts, but how can I get a photo Instagram Page URL? So, when I click on image it opens this image in the official Instagram page of this profile?

```
<% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>
     <%= instagram.likes[:count] %>
     <%= instagram.comments[:count] %>
     <%= instagram.images.standard_resolution.url %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram returns a `link` attribute on root of media json:

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent

So, I guess that you can access the link attribute by `<%= instagram.link %>`